# React and Redux: why isn't my value not displaying from reducer, when using mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

In my react project, I've hooked up redux and added a reducer with an object that holds a key and value pair: "key: 'hello'". I imported it into my index.js in my reducers folder, and am trying to use it inside a container, using MapStateToProps. For whatever reason, the value isn't showing up! When I console.log this.props.reducer, I am returned the correct object, but when I type in this.props.reducer.key I'm returned 'undefined'. Why is this happening? I've never had this problem, before...

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FirstComponent from './components/firstComponent.js';
import FirstContainer from './containers/firstContainer.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <FirstComponent />
        <FirstContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

my reducer:

```
export default function() {
    return [
        {
            key: 'hello',
        }
    ]
}
```

my index.js inside the reducers folder

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import firstReducer from './reducer.js';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    reducer: firstReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

my container:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class FirstContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                value: {this.props.reducer.key}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        reducer: state.reducer
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FirstContainer);
```

I should see: 'value: hello' on my screen, but I just see 'value: ' displayed

Answer (score 1):

why your reducer returns an array and doesn't accept any arguments?

usually the reducer looks somewhat like this, so it accepts 2 params (first one being the previous state of the app) and returns an object

```
const initialState = { key: 'not hello' };

expert default functions(prevState = initialState, value) {
   const newStateObject = { key: value };

   return newStateObject;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just figured it out! I created an array and then placed the object inside of it, so I have to write this.props.reducer[0].key if i want to get the value. I just wanted to eventually create a reducer holding several objects with data, to map through in my container. That's why it doesn't look like a usual reducer :). Thank you for your reply, though!

Comment: well if you know what you are doing, then by all means, return an array :) Although from my experience it's easier to handle reducer that is in a shape of an object, and inside it, under keys store different data structures that you require. Various react node modules are also assuming that so bear in mind that you will have to do a bit more customizations around them in case you want to use ie. react-router etc (I'm not 100% sure but it's quite likely)

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer is incorrect, you can set the initial state, and thereafter the function is either supposed to return the state unchanged, or the next state if it receives an action it's interested in.

```
const initialState = { key: 'hello'};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
       // dispatch({ type: 'UpdateKey', value: 'new value' })
       case 'UpdateKey': {
         return {
           ...state,
           key: action.value,
         };
       }
    }

    return state;
}
```